# Nextjs link with URL object not working when using element id in pathname

Tags: reactjs, typescript, url, next.js, router

I've added translations to my website which requires me to now use an URL object when creating my links. I don't have any problems with this anywhere except for when i want click a link that is pointed to /#contact for example.

when i'm just using `href='/#contact'` this will work. But if i were to use `href={{ pathname: "/#contact", query: query }}` this will fail.

I've already looked into the next/link documentation and it only shows these things separately, but not when working together.

Comment: When using the [URL object format](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object) in `href`, values will be URL encoded (meaning `#` becomes `%23`). Instead, you can pass the query params in the `href` as a string too, e.g. `href="/#contact?param=value"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution `href={{ pathname: "/", query: query ,hash: "contact"}}` and it works for me.

Comment: This works nicely, but it's not in the docs for the link component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10494#issuecomment-595711360) can help you?

**Edit:** Indeed, it seems like with query, /#contact is transformed to %23contact. Is this your problem too?
If so, as a workaround, you can parse the query params and use only `href`, as such:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';

const Contact = () => {
  const query = { name: 'john', age: 10 };

  const params = Object.keys(query).reduce(
    (acc, el, index) =>
      acc.concat(`${index === 0 ? '?' : '&'}${el}=${query[el]}`),
    '',
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/#contact${params}`}>Click me</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Which results in `http://localhost:3000/#contact?name=john&age=10`

Comment: Afraid not, using `href="/#contact" as={{ pathname: "/#contact", query: query }}` does not work

Comment: since I can't post code in comments I edited my answer with a potential workaround @MichaelVanhoutte

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. This is probably because the query i use is function from next-export-i18n `const [query] = useLanguageQuery();`